# How to create BeanPropertyRowMapper from Generic class?

Tags: java, spring

I have a class

```
public class WFWSimpleDAOImpl<ObjectClass> implements WFWSimpleDAO<ObjectClass> {
```

that contains a method

```
public List<ObjectClass> retrieve(Object[] params) throws Exception {
```

that returns a typed list of objects

```
return (List<ObjectClass>) getJdbcTemplate().query(sqlToExec, params, new BeanPropertyRowMapper<ObjectClass>())
```

BeanPropertyRowMapper constructor requires parameter to define mapped class

```
BeanPropertyRowMapper(Class mappedClass)
```

Roughly I need next:

```
BeanPropertyRowMapper(ObjectClass)
```

But I get compiler error message

```
ObjectClass can not be resolved to a variable
```

How should I make class cast in the situation?

Comment: @peeskillet yeah, that was first I made... but get error: Illegal class literal for the type parameter ObjectClass

Comment: Did you pass it to the constructor? I don't think you need to paramaterize it. `new BeanPropertyRowMapper(ObjectClass.class)`. See [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/BeanPropertyRowMapper.html#BeanPropertyRowMapper%28java.lang.Class%29)

Comment: @peeskillet Yes, I mean the same: when I write new BeanPropertyRowMapper(ObjectClass.class) then I get compiler message:  Illegal class literal for the type parameter ObjectClass

Comment: You are confusing matters by using `ObjectClass` as a generic type parameter. It is conventional to use a single letter eg `T`.

Comment: yes, I have understood it. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution is so not trivial as I thought. At the end I used reflection and made so:

```
Class<ObjectClass> classOfObjectClass = (Class<ObjectClass>) ((ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
return (List<ObjectClass>) getJdbcTemplate().query(sqlToExec, params, new BeanPropertyRowMapper(classOfObjectClass));
```